# mysql,while sorting 2 columns one column doesn't get sorted

Tags: mysql

Write a query to display the entire contents of the table after performing an inner join on role table and user table, sorted by role name and then by name of the user. 
This is my problem statement.

```
select role.name,role.id,user.name,user.emailid,user.password,
user.phonenumber,user.profile_id,user.role_id,user.username 
from user 
inner join role 
on role.id=user.role_id 
order by role.name,user.name
;
```

> role.name is sorted but the problem is user.name column is not
>   sorted.why??

Comment: post your table input, the output from your query, describe why its not what you expect and specify what you do expect..

Comment: provide some data and the query. only in that case any one can help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be aware that user.name will be sorted after role. So within the same roles user names will be sorted. You are sure that it is not what happened?

Comment: user.name column gives an unordered list

Comment: As @amdixon said, show us some output. Maybe this way we will be able to help.